# queryRunner in read operation (typeorm, nestjs)

Tags: transactions, nestjs, typeorm

I work in nestjs with typeorm(mysql:8.0.31).
I know that when i'm using transaction make queryRunner like below

```
async createMany(users: User[]) {
  const queryRunner = this.dataSource.createQueryRunner();

  await queryRunner.connect();
  await queryRunner.startTransaction();
  try {
    await queryRunner.manager.save(users[0]);
    await queryRunner.manager.save(users[1]);

    await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
  } catch (err) {
    // since we have errors lets rollback the changes we made
    await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
  } finally {
    // you need to release a queryRunner which was manually instantiated
    await queryRunner.release();
  }
}
```

problem is, when i execute read operation like `findOneOrFail` multiple times in one service handler, i found that there exists connection issue.

although the db connection set to 2, in dev environment.
it is weired.

is it just lack of db connection or other problems?
plz give your opinion.
thank you.